# Mod_rewrite help when removing part of a URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove a directory from any URLS that contain it. It's a wordpress blog.

Currently the following urls 404, and probably many others:

```
site.com/blog/archives/yyyy/mm/dd/
site.com/blog/archives/yyyy/mm/dd/post-title/
site.com/blog/archives/author/username
```

However, all of these urls work fine when they are in this format:

```
site.com/blog/yyyy/mm/dd/
site.com/blog/yyyy/mm/dd/post-title/
site.com/blog/author/username
```

So pretty much I need to take any url that has the director /archive/ in it, regardless of what comes after it, and remove it. I've tried lots of example online with no luck. I feel like I must be doing something wrong and not realizing it.

The last thing I tried was this, thinking it would be a very broad rule and work. No dice.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/archives/(.*) $1/$2 [NC]
```

Here is my current .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)\.html /blog/?p=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Generally, you want to leave the WordPress-supplied section alone and put your new stuff ahead of it. I'm a bit concerned about your defining a RewriteBase (/blog/) and then using /blog/ in the RewriteRule... does it give you /blog/blog/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before the `# BEGIN WordPress` line add:

```
RewriteRule ^archives/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, it has to be within the IfModule and after RewriteEngine On. You can add another section before the WP section (avoid modifying the WP section), if you want.

Comment: @PhilPerry You can create another `<IfModule>` container if you want, but you don't need to have it before a `RewriteEngine On`, or `RewriteBase`, those are global directives, they get applied globally, whether or not it's in an `<IfModule>` container or not.

Comment: I didn't say that. If you simply stick in a RewriteRule where you said to, it will not be following a RewriteEngine On. I said that you need to add another RewriteEngine On, and (if needed) an IfModule. It's usually a good idea to leave the stock WP section at the end, and add any new stuff ahead of it.

Comment: @PhilPerry I'm saying that [the `RewriteEngine` can be anywhere in the entire file, it's applied globally](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlgJ.png). You don't need another one, unless it's just for readability or redundancy

Comment: Thanks, Jon that did the trick. Much appreciated. I'm almost positive I tried that before without success. Must have made an error or something.